# Create new column with group label based on condition tested in a different column

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, conditional-statements, grouping

I want to create group labels based on a condition tested in another column. In particular, if there is the value of `directionChange.equalTo(1)`, I want to start a new segment (label). The should be result is given in column `segmentNr` the result produced by my code is in `nSegment`.
I assume it is not possible to do for-like assignments this way. 
Finally, I would like to calculate different aspects, such as sum, mean, max of the value per segment (not in the scope of the question).

Input example:

```
+---+-----+---------------+---------+--------+
| id|value|directionChange|segmentNr|nSegment|
+---+-----+---------------+---------+--------+
|  1| 11.0|              0|        1|       1|
|  2|-22.0|              1|        2|       1|
|  3| 34.0|              0|        2|       1|    
|  4|-47.0|              1|        3|       1|    
|  5| 61.0|              1|        4|       1|    
|  6| 22.0|              0|        4|       1|    
|  7|  5.0|              0|        4|       1|    
|  8| -7.0|              1|        5|       1|    
+---+-----+---------------+---------+--------+
```

Function to add the new column using the input dataset:

```
public static Dataset<Row> createSegments(Dataset<Row> dataset, String columnName, int start, String newColumnName) throws Exception
{
    int test = 1;
    Dataset<Row> resultDataset = dataset.withColumn(newColumnName, //
            functions.when(dataset.col(columnName).equalTo(1), (start = start + 1))//
                    .otherwise(start));

    return resultDataset;
}
```

The function is called as follows:

```
dataset = createSegments(dataset, "directionChange", 0, "nSegment");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done using a `Window` function. However, since you do not have a column to partition the data it could get very slow for large datasets. This could be improved by using a `partitionBy(column)` on the `Window` object below. However, this would require a good column to partition by and the final result would be split into parts as well.

The idea behind the solution is to make a cumulative sum of the `directionChange` column when ordered by the `id` column. In Scala:

```
val window = Window.orderBy("id").rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.currentRow)
val df2 = dataset.withColumn("nSegment", sum($"directionChange").over(window) + 1)
```

Java code:

```
WindowSpec window = Window.orderBy("id").rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding(), Window.currentRow()); 
Dataset<Row> df2 = dataset.withColumn("nSegment", functions.sum("directionChange").over(window));
```

In older versions of Spark (< 2.1.0) use:

```
rowsBetween(Long.MinValue, 0)
```

This will create a new column `nSegment` that is equal to the `segmentNr` from the input data. For the next step you can use `groupBy("nSegment").agg(...)` to calculate different metrics for each segment.

Comment: Dear Shaido, thx for the hint with the window and the sum. I translated it to the following Java Code. It works for the given example. Now, I am looking for a solution for millions of lines ;-)WindowSpec window = Window.orderBy("id").rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding(), Window.currentRow());
   Dataset<Row> df2 = dataset.withColumn("nSegment", functions.sum("directionChange").over(window));
   
   df2.show();

Comment: @ACommodus: I don't think you can do it in any better way (but I could be wrong). It would help greatly if you could partition the dataframe before the computation, but this means that you need a relevant column to partition by as well as your results will be split into different parts. If it's possible in your case, simply add a `partitionBy(columnName)` to the `Window`.

Comment: @ACommodus: I also added your Java code for future viewers :)